# Retrieve rows from dataframe don't exit in another dataframe pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, isin

I need rows from df1 doesn't exist in df2 based on 3 columns [Time1, ID1, Order1].
I need df3 has rows of df1 don't exist on df2
Note: Time1 is in datetime format,

Example

input

df1

| Time1 | ID1 | Order1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/14/2022 6:10:32 PM | X | A |
| 9/15/2022 2:45:57 AM | Y | B |
| 9/15/2022 11:08:26 AM | Z | C |

df2

| Time2 | ID2 | Order2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/14/2022 6:15:35 PM | X | A |
| 12/14/2022 6:00:35 PM | Y | B |
| 9/15/2022 2:45:57 AM | Y | B |

output
df3

| Time1 | ID1 | Order1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/14/2022 6:10:32 PM | X | A |
| 9/15/2022 11:08:26 AM | Z | C |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with indicator and indexing:

```
df3 = df1.loc[df1.merge(df2, left_on=['Time1', 'ID1', 'Order1'],
                             right_on=['Time2', 'ID2', 'Order2'],
                        how='left', indicator=True)
                 .query('_merge == "left_only"').index
             ]
```

Or:

```
df3 = df1.loc[df1.merge(df2, left_on=['Time1', 'ID1', 'Order1'],
                             right_on=['Time2', 'ID2', 'Order2'],
                        how='left', indicator=True)
                 ['_merge'].eq('left_only')
             ]
```

Output:

```
                   Time1 ID1 Order1
0  12/14/2022 6:10:32 PM   X      A
2  9/15/2022 11:08:26 AM   Z      C
```